# How to reset array when item is deleted from the grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a modal window when it opens i have grid and i am setting `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` to `$scope.selectedOwners` array that is grid dataSource , now when i delete this item by using `$scope.deleteOwner` row got deleted from grid  but when you open modal window again row got populated again.

How can i resolve this issue using angularJs ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.selectedOwners = [];
    $scope.opencntrlOwner = function() {
        this.ctrlOwnerModal.open().center();
        if ($state.is('app.editControl')) {
          $scope.selectedOwners = angular.copy($scope.controlDTO.controlOwners);
          console.log('EDIT CONTROL OWNERS DATA', $scope.selectedOwners);
        }
        controlOwnersDataSource();
    };

 $scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem) {
      angular.forEach($scope.selectedOwners, function(owner, $index) {
        if (owner.workerKey === dataItem.workerKey) {
            $scope.selectedOwners.splice($index, 1);
        }
        controlOwnersDataSource();
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to me the fact that every time you open the modal, you do a copy of `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` but on delete, you are deleting only from the `$scope.selectedOwners`. Add a splice to the `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` as well on delete, and it should work.

Comment: I understand your point but `$Scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` data i am setting it to `$scope.selectedOwners` so if i am deleting from $scope.selectedOwners this array is empty should not display any values in  the grid because `$scope.selectedOwners` is a grid dataSource.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't really understand, are you saying that you cannot delete anything from `$Scope.controlDTO.controlOwners` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an owner from `$scope.selectedOwners` it is not being deleted from  `$scope.controlDTO.controlOwners`, so you would also want to splice it out of that array.